# How to write a multiprocess program from a multithreaded program in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have this *multithreaded* program with two threads and I want to convert it to a *multiprocess* program so that the two thread become two process and it tells which process finishes first.

Here is the mutlithreaded program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define OUTPUTNAME "write.out"
#define OUTPUTNAME1 "fprint.out"

void *syscall_writer_function();
void *stdlibrary_writer_function();
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int counter = 0;

main()
{
    int rc1, rc2;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute functions */

    if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &syscall_writer_function, NULL)) )

    {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc1);
    }

    if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &stdlibrary_writer_function, NULL)) )
    {
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rc2);
    }

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *syscall_writer_function()
{
    long i;
    int fd;
    if ((fd=open(OUTPUTNAME,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT,0644)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s. Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<50000; i++) { /* write 50,000 Ys with write */
        if (write(fd,"Y",1) < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );
    counter++;
    printf("Syscall finished\n");
    printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
    close(fd);

    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );
}

void *stdlibrary_writer_function()
{
    long i;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp=fopen(OUTPUTNAME1,"w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s. Bye.\n",OUTPUTNAME1);
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<400000; i++) { /* write 400,000 Xs with fprintf */
        if (fprintf(fp,"X") < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Can't write. Bye\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    counter++;
    printf("Stdlibrary finished\n");
    printf("Counter value: %d\n",counter);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

How to convert it to a **multiprocess** program in C?

Comment: Instead of using `pthread_create`, use [`fork`](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node22.html).

Comment: ... and prepare yourself for sharing memory if these threads have any data-overlaps (like `counter`). You're going to also likely be learning how to share a pthread mutex in shared memory as well. Oh, what fun you have in store!

Comment: Why not just make two different programs, and measure the time that each one takes?

Comment: @WhozCraig: he doesn't really need the counter in a multi-process system; the `waitpid()` call can be used to get which child exited first (the difference will be large enough).  Or you can print hi-res timestamps in the children before they exit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I concur, but *need* had nothing to do with that comment. *That* program, forking instead of threading (a bit of an irony, as it isn't uncommon for systems to pthread via shared memory and process forking anyway), would use such a setup. A *rewrite* would certainly not if the author targeted multi-process from the get-go, I concur completely.

Comment: I am just learning this stuff, and don't understand much of what's commented here. :(

Comment: @WhozCraig could you explain what you said.

Comment: @RSahu Just that literally?

Comment: @LindaNu,  looking at your program, it's that simple. I would start by using `fork` to create one child process. Once that works, I would expand the program to create two child processes.